# How can I access the array(2-d) added to ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I access the 2D arrays added to an `ArrayList`?

```
import java.util.*;
class Input
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       ArrayList arr=new ArrayList();
       int x;
       System.out.println("enter no of arrays");
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       x=sc.nextInt();
       int c=1;
       while(c<=x)
       {
         System.out.println("enter a case:");
         int[][] ch=new int[4][4];
         for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
         {
           System.out.println();
           for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           {
             ch[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
           }
         }
         arr.add(ch);
         c++;
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a type for the ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<int[][]> arr;
```

Then `arr.get(index)` will correctly be treated as an `int[][]`.

Answer (score 3):

Parametrize the `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<int[][]> arr = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
```

Then you can simply access the elements as `int[][]`s via [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29).